# Where does the superfactorial sit on the fast growing hiearchy?

Tags: functions

### Question

Using the definition
$$
\text{sf}(x) = \prod_{n=1}^{x} n!
$$
Where would the Superfactorial ($\text{sf}(x)$) sit on the fast-growing hiearchy?

### Context

The reason I am asking is because recently I have been pondering, which is faster growing, the hyperfactorial ($f_2(f_2(x))$ on the fast growing hiearchy), the exponential factorial ($f_3(x)$ on the fast-growing hiearchy) or the superfactorial?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Googology (see [Section: Sloane and Plouffe](https://googology.fandom.com/wiki/Superfactorial)), the given definition of superfactorial has a growth rate of about $f_2(n)$, which is $f_{1}^n(n)=n \cdot 2^n$ (see [Definition of fast growing functions](https://googology.fandom.com/wiki/Fast-growing_hierarchy)).